# Google Chrome Canary seems to have "hidden" some features

Tags: google-chrome

When I open the DevTools options in my latest version of Chrome (30.0), I have an "Overrides" tab which lets me emulate touch events.

In Chrome Canary (32.0), this tab seems to be gone. How can I emulate touch events then?

(PS note that in Canary I have to manually toggle experimental features inside `chrome://flags` before seeing an "Experiments" tab which lets me "Show Overrides in the drawer", but I still don't figure out what it does)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 32.0.1677.0 Canary the Overrides tab has been repositioned to the Console section. If you hit Esc you will see it there.

Remember, when using Canary you get the latest Chrome experimentation, so maybe this will change again in the future.

Comment: So glad I found this. I was trapped in touch emulation mode!

Comment: Dont mix up "console section" with "console tab".. Click on "elements tab" and hit ESC to find the emulation mode.

Comment: Well, excuse my poor choice of words, but as I mentioned the Canary build is subject to perpetual change. The "official" Chrome team terminology is "Console **drawer**". 

You can find this in the Stable Chrome Developer Tools Settings page, in the Overrides Tab. And yes, you are _partially_ right, you can access the Console drawer by hitting the ESC key in any tab other than the Console tab.

Answer (score 1):

don't be so sure. This is already in beta and its irritating